# Polynomials divide each other in a finite field implies they are constant multiples of each other

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

If two polynomials divide each other in a field such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, then they certainly have to differ by a constant: $g(x) = k f(x)$.

But what about a finite field? If polynomials divide each other, are they still constant multiples of each other by some $k \in F$ where $f$ is finite?

My logic is that if $f(x)\mid g(x)$ and $g(x)\mid f(x)$ in a finite field, then there exists polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that $g(x)p(x) = f(x)$ and $f(x)q(x) = g(x)$.

Now $f(x) q(x) p(x) = f(x)$ or $q(x) p(x) = 1$. But I am stuck here. I doubt that  $q(x) p(x) = 1$ could alone imply that $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ are constants in a finite field since inverse polynomials can exist.

Comment: Hint: $\deg(pq)=\deg p+\deg q$.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard ! I understand now.

Comment: Inverse polynomials cannot exist (unless they are constants). The set of units in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxx, I am trying to understand the same situation! :-) May I ask you something? The author got that $qp=1$ and Bernard wrote that $\deg(qp)=\deg(q)+\deg(q)$. Doesn't this mean that one of $q$ and $p$ is a constant? But if $g=cf$ where $c$ is the constant, we can then write $f=\dfrac{1}{c}g$, which contradicts with the fact that only one of $q$ and $p$ is a constant.

Comment: @SAQ Where is there an assumption that only one of $q$ and $p$ is a constant? If $qp=1$ then they must both be constant (degree $0$).